# Should I index DateTime in SQLite?

Tags: sql, sqlite

Will it make it faster to find date > a certain date?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general yes, but keep in mind that SQLite only uses one index per-table (except in the case of OR clauses).  Always use [`EXPLAIN`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_explain.html) to find out how the engine will process a given query.